# Readable implementation of Trie in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, trie

Need reviews on my readable implementation of Trie. Also what other methods can or should be added to this data structure.

```
from collections import defaultdict


class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = TrieNode()

    def add(self, word):
        curr = self.root
        for letter in word:
            node = curr.children.get(letter)
            if not node:
                node = TrieNode()
                curr.children[letter] = node
            curr = node
        curr.end_of_word = True

    def search(self, word):
        curr = self.root
        for w in word:
            node = curr.children.get(w)
            if not node:
                return False
            curr = node
        return curr.end_of_word

    def all_words_beginning_with_prefix(self, prefix):
        curr = self.root
        for letter in prefix:
            node = curr.children.get(letter)
            if curr is None:
                raise KeyError("Prefix not in Trie")
            curr = node
        result = []

        def _find(n, p):
            if n.end_of_word:
                result.append(p)
            for k, v in n.children.items():
                _find(v, p + k)

        _find(curr, prefix)
        return result


class TrieNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = defaultdict(TrieNode)
        self.end_of_word = False
```

This is the calling client that can be used to test the code.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    trie = Trie()
    trie.add('foobar')
    trie.add('foo')
    trie.add('bar')
    trie.add('foob')
    trie.add('foof')

    print(list(trie.all_words_beginning_with_prefix('foo')))
```

Answer (score 3):

## naming

Your naming is not consistent. sometimes you use `letter`, sometimes `w` for the same thing. I generally avoid 1-letter variable names, but if you use them, be consistent

## dict.setdefault

using `dict.setdefault`, you can simplify your `Trie.add` method significantly

```
def add(self, word):
    curr = self.root
    for letter in word:
        curr = curr.children.setdefault(letter, TrieNode())
    curr.end_of_word = True
```

Then you can also change the `TrieNode.children` to an ordinary `dict`.

## string representation

For debugging, it can be handy to have a string representation of a Node

```
def __repr__(self):
    return f'TrieNode(end_of_word={self.end_of_word}, children={tuple(self.children)})'
```

## getting a node

Currently, there is no way in your Trie to get a node. Having this method would simplify the rest of the implementation

```
def __getitem__(self, word):
    curr = self.root
    for letter in word:
        curr = curr.children[letter]
    return curr

def get(self, word):
    return self[word]
```

If you changed the type of `TrieNode.children` to a `dict` instead of a `defaultdict`, this will raise a `KeyError`. If you left it at `defaultdict`, this will return an empty `TrieNode`: `'TrieNode(end_of_word=False, children=())'`, check for it, and raise the `KeyError` yourself

would simplify the rest of the implementation

```
def __getitem__(self, word):
    curr = self.root
    for letter in word:
        curr = curr.children[letter]
    if not (curr.children or curr.end_of_word):
        raise KeyError(f'{word} not in Trie')
    return curr
```

> ```
> trie['foo']
>
> TrieNode(end_of_word=True, children=('b', 'f'))
> ```

## Search

With the method to get a Node, Search becomes as trivial as

```
def search(self, word):
    try:
        return self[word].end_of_word
    except KeyError:
        return False
```

## words starting with prefix

This name can be shortened to `starts_with`.

Here, I would move the iteration to find the 'child-words' to the `TrieNode`, and recursively descend down the nodes

```
def child_words(self, prefix=''):
    if self.end_of_word:
        yield prefix
    for letter, node in self.children.items():
        word = prefix + letter
        yield from node.child_words(word)
```

`Trie.starts_with` becomes simply:

```
def starts_with(self, prefix):
    try:
        node = self[prefix]
    except KeyError:
        raise KeyError(f"Prefix `{prefix}` not in Trie")
    return node.child_words(prefix)
```

which returns the generator yielding words

> ```
> list(trie.starts_with('foo))
>
> ['foo', 'foob', 'foobar', 'foof']
> ```

If you want to, you can even add in a `inclusive` boolean flag

```
def child_words(self, prefix='', inclusive=True):
    if inclusive and self.end_of_word:
        yield prefix
    for letter, node in self.children.items():
        word = prefix + letter
        yield from node.child_words(word, inclusive=True)
```

## full code

```
class TrieNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = dict()
        self.end_of_word = False

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'TrieNode(end_of_word={self.end_of_word},' \
               f' children={tuple(self.children)})'

    def child_words(self, prefix='', inclusive=True):
        if inclusive and self.end_of_word:
            yield prefix
        for letter, node in self.children.items():
            word = prefix + letter
            yield from node.child_words(word, inclusive=True)


class Trie_Maarten:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = TrieNode()

    def add(self, word):
        curr = self.root
        for letter in word:
            curr = curr.children.setdefault(letter, TrieNode())
        curr.end_of_word = True

    def __getitem__(self, word):
        curr = self.root
        for letter in word:
            curr = curr.children[letter]
        return curr

    def get(self, word):
        return self[word]

    def search(self, word):
        try:
            return self[word].end_of_word
        except KeyError:
            return False

    def starts_with(self, prefix, inclusive=True):
        try:
            node = self[prefix]
        except KeyError:
            raise KeyError(f"Prefix `{prefix}` not in Trie")
        return node.child_words(prefix, inclusive)
```